# Select Until Find NULL Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have an issue where i tried to select from a column until it identify null value. I can't used row count since i am afraid new item added will change the row count. So the data count is not fixed but 3 row is null is fixed.

This is the source example

[image: This is the source example]

After load to SSIS

[image: After load to SSIS]

```
SELECT  [F1] FROM TEST_TBL WHERE F1 BETWEEN 'MTH' AND NULL
```

My plan is to select from value MTH until it find column that null and save it into a new table. Same goes for the other one, select from value YTD until it find column that null.

So far i cant solve it and i am still new in SQL. Thanks

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first `NULL`" value, unless you have a column that specifies the ordering of the rows.

Comment: @EzLo why answer the question in a comment?   Now it can't be marked as answered.

Comment: @EzLo but it will be hard for second table ? let say i added row count, WHERE RowNumber > 9 AND RowNumber <(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YTD_TEST).

Comment: @EzLo but will it work if a new data for MTH added which it will effect the row number. So rownumber for YTD is no longer 9. Correct me if i am wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a the original excel row number on your SSIS flow and store it on SQL, you can easily pick the rows you need, since you now have an ordered set of rows.

**Set up:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Excel') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Excel

CREATE TABLE #Excel (
    ID INT IDENTITY, 
    CellContent VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Excel (
    CellContent)
VALUES
    ('MTH'),
    ('BANK FINANCING'),
    ('CLR A/C - ERROR'),
    ('COMPANY/CORPORATE'),
    ('NULL'),
    ('NULL'),
    ('NULL'),
    ('YTD'),
    ('Account Type'),
    ('BANK FINANCING'),
    ('CLR A/C - ERROR')
```

**Solution**:

```
DECLARE @v_StartingCellContent VARCHAR(100) = 'MTH' -- Change here the first value you want to be displayed from

DECLARE @v_LowerLimit INT = (SELECT MIN(E.ID) FROM #Excel AS E WHERE E.CellContent = @v_StartingCellContent)
DECLARE @v_HigherLimit INT = (SELECT MIN(E.ID) FROM #Excel AS E WHERE E.ID > @v_LowerLimit AND E.CellContent = 'NULL')

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Excel AS T
WHERE
    T.ID >= @v_LowerLimit AND 
    (@v_HigherLimit IS NULL OR T.ID < @v_HigherLimit)
ORDER BY
    T.ID
```

**Result**:

```
ID  CellContent
1   MTH
2   BANK FINANCING
3   CLR A/C - ERROR
4   COMPANY/CORPORATE
```